# AngularJS : Toggle to modify attribute in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In the project I am working on, I am applying a ui-sort via Angular on a to-do list and am trying to get a toggle to work for when a user is editing tasks.  My current method of testing this toggle is employing the use of a button to toggle sorting on and off.

My strategy is this:
Employ an angular directive to generate an initial template with sorting on.
Add a button which, when clicked, modifies a scope variable in the controller ($scope.sortingEnabled) to toggle between true and false.
Inside my directive, I have a watch set on 'sortingEnabled' in a link function to add/remove the sorting attribute from a .

Here is the  in todo.html before I tried employing a directive:
sortableOptions is a function written to re-order the todos on internal records.

```
<ul class="unstyled" ng-model="todos" ui-sortable="sortableOptions">
<!-- list items here via ng-repeat -->
</ul>
```

The following is the code in todo.html after my directive:

```
<sortable></sortable>
```

And my current draft for the directive inside todo-directives.js:

```
app.directive('sortable', function() {

    var innerHtml = '<li ng-repeat="todo in todos" class="item">' +
        '<span ng-model="todo.name" >{{todo.name}}</span> ' +
        '</li>';

    var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch('sortingEnabled', function() {
            if(scope.sortingEnabled === true) {
                element.contents().attr("ui-sortable", "sortableOptions");
                //needed else ui-sortable added as a class for <ul> initially for
                //some reason
                element.contents().removeClass("ui-sortable");
            }
            else {
                element.contents().removeAttr("ui-sortable");
                //needed else ui-sortable added as a class for <ul> initially for
                //some reason
                element.contents().removeClass("ui-sortable");
            }
        });


    };
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<ul class="unstyled" ng-model="todos" ui-sortable="sortableOptions"  ng-transclude>' + innerHtml + '</ul>',
        link: link
    };

});
```

This code works in the source code view of Chrome's debugger, but the view does not properly refresh.  I have tried scope.$apply() within the watch function but get a $digest already running error.  I have also tried $compile, but my understanding of how that works is severely lacking, so I get errors of which I do not remember.
Am I missing something crucial, or doing things incorrectly?  I am unsure, as my understanding is low, being that I have been leaning Angular for a few weeks.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular directive supports watching when the sortable options change:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.uiSortable, function(newVal, oldVal){
```

So all you had to do was look at the jqueryui sortable documentation, and update the correct property on the plugin.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/D6VavCW1BmWSSXhK5qk7?p=preview

Html

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="items">
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
 </ul>
<button ng-click="sortableOptions.disabled = !sortableOptions.disabled">Is Disabled: {{sortableOptions.disabled}}</button>
```

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    disabled: true
  };
});
```

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is toggle the sorting feature on the list.  I tried to generate a template, and then modify its attributes, either removing the attribute when the sort is toggled off ($scope.sortEnabled false) or is toggled on ($scope.sortEnabled true).  This would then trigger the watch I have set, either removing or adding the ui-sortable="sortingOptions" respectively, which would then result in the view/DOM refreshing to apply this effect to the list.

This person I believe was trying the same thing as me:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/13Mc7hry0bE

Comment: this person's answer seems correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150887/how-to-dynamically-disable-ui-sortable-directive-in-angular-ui

Comment: hmm, yes I remember seeing that question yesterday and attempting to modify my watch with element.sortable("disable"); yields the following error: Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'.  I am a newbie with this, so I am not sure if that function is even compatible.